# Error Launching IDEA: No JVM Installation Found

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide

I am trying to learn Python from an online course that I purchased.  The instructor uses IntelliJ IDEA as an IDE and since I am trying to follow along I am trying to use it as well.  When I download IntelliJ IDEA and then try to open it I receive the following error message: "No JVM Installation found.  Please install a 32 bit JDK.  If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_Home variable in COmputer>System Properties>System Settings>Environmental Variables"

I tried googling the issue and found my way to the Oracle website where they offered JDK downloads.  However there was no 32bit windows version available.

1. What is a JDK?
2. Why do I need a JDK for Python development?
3. How can I download a 32 bit version of JDK?
4. What is an easy to learn IDE for Python?  I've tried Visual Studio Code and PyCharm and have had issues with the set up of both and have not found many helpful articles/videos.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried googling the issue and found my way to the Oracle website
>   where they offered JDK downloads. However there was no 32bit windows
>   version available.

x86 download is the one you need: [jdk-8u131-windows-i586.exe](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

> Why do I need a JDK for Python development?

IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm are written in Java and run under JVM. 64-bit JVM is bundled and is used automatically, but 32-bit version is not bundled with the recent versions to save on the download size, so you need to install it manually.

> How can I download a 32 bit version of JDK?

See above or use [JetBrains Runtime](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/openjdk8-windows-x86#files). Latest version: [jbsdk8u152b927.2_windows_x86.tar.gz](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbsdk8u152b927.2_windows_x86.tar.gz). [Instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

> What is an easy to learn IDE for Python? I've tried Visual Studio Code
>   and PyCharm and have had issues with the set up of both and have not
>   found many helpful articles/videos.

IntelliJ IDEA has the same support for Python as PyCharm.

You can use PyCharm Community to get started or [PyCharm Edu](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-edu/).

Please avoid asking questions to recommend a book or IDE on StackOverflow, it's considered off-topic in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the root folder. And you should find the 64 bits version in it. You can then create a short cut for that.You should be fine.