# Unable to open Intellij Idea using command line

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I am trying to open Intellij Idea using `idea .` getting below error. **My windows is 64 bit.**

```
E:\>java -version
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

E:\>javac -version
javac 15.0.1
```

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Launching IDEA: No JVM Installation Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709252/error-launching-idea-no-jvm-installation-found)

Comment: What is your Windows bittness - 32bit or 64bit? If you have 32bit Windows, then should download and install Oradle 32bit JDK version as advised above and set IDE to use it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

Comment: Do you add JAVA_HOME to your variables? in above picture you didn't note that.

Comment: `C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1`

Comment: Do you install appropriate 64bit version of intelliJ?

Comment: Installed Setup on my machine is 64-bit only

Comment: Download IDE form https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ for Windows. Delete existing [IDE config directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) If you have defined IDE-specific JDK environment variable - remove it (see the list of variables the IDE checks here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879 ).