# JAVA_HOME not found in your environment

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNi6L.png)

How can I fix this i even tried reinstalling jdk and setting up Environment variables but still the error is unresolved

Comment: Might help: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: C:\Users\Shamanth>ECHO %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19

Comment: Also set the PATH variable as advised in the Oracle docs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Launching IDEA: No JVM Installation Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709252/error-launching-idea-no-jvm-installation-found)